# Cannot login to heroku

Tags: heroku

When I try to login to my heruko account it says:

> Post
>   https://api.heroku.com/login?username=xxxxxxx%40gmail.com&password=XXXXXXXX:
>   dial tcp: lookup api.heroku.com on 127.0.1.1:53: cannot unmarshal DNS
>   message

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2

Comment: Found any solution yet? I am stuck at the same issue.

Comment: Not yet bro. I stopped searching because of not getting any solution. Let me know if you get any.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by un-installing the current Heroku Toolbelt and re-installing it.

First Uninstalled-

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove heroku-toolbelt
```

Then, installed-

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

I had similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534594/cant-login-to-heroku-anymore) and could solve it by the above process.
Hope this will help as an answer to most of the question/s related to this error.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, but after some digging , i resolved it by modifying my `DNS`

- `DNS` to `8.8.8.8`.

It worked like a charm thenafter.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using this:

```
sudo su
heroku login
```

Comment: More details as to why this actually solves the problem would be great

Comment: I can not explain why.
but searching I found this:
http://www.pqwee.com/2016/heroku-setup-for-python-and-flask/

Comment: Tried almost every solution out there, but didn't work for me. So, I have given up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I removed non-aplhanumeric characters from my password (ie I changed my password to not include them), and it worked.

Just to clarify: a password like passw0r8$#% works on the website but not the command line, but passw0r8 does work on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything above and nothing worked. What got it working for me was adding this line to my `/etc/hosts`:

```
23.21.149.112 api.heroku.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I came cross this issue also,finally I solved it by heroku update and use a proxy.I guess this is kind of net-trouble.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score -1):

I just encountered this problem,it took me half a day to solve it .As a beginner,I worked in Ubuntu 15 ,using Python 2.7.  (Google was blocked because of GFW.)
Just Three steps.

1.Modify The password only composed of letters and numbers,**contain no "?","_","*","&"etc**.

2.I have tried DNS "8.8.8.8""8.8.4.4""114.114.114.114",but failed.
I modified DNS for **"223.5.5.5" "223.6.6.6"**(alidns)  terminally.

(  ~$ **sudo  vi  /etc/resolv.conf**
Then modify 'nameserver xx.xx.xx.xx'   and save.)

3. Use   ~$ **heroku  auth:login**